# Cypress - calendar change month, until specific month is found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress

I have a calendar. This calendar shows one month per time. Here it is: https://react-dates.github.io/react-dates/?path=/story/drp-calendar-props--single-month

My calendar automatically shows a date 3 years old. In this case November 2019.

I want to test April 2020.

I need the calendar to click the next arrows, until `cy.contains('April 2020')`.

I wrote the following:

```
cy.get('.CalendarMonth').then($calendarPopover => {
  if ($calendarPopover.text().includes('February 2020')) {
    cy.contains('February 2020')
  } else {
    cy.get('.calendar-arrow-right')
      .click()
      .then(el => {
        if (!$calendarPopover.text().includes('February 2020')) {
          el.click()
        }
      })
  }
})
```

But it stops after the first month change.
How can I make it continue until the IF condition will be met?

Thank you

Comment: Your snippet has no ostensible recursion, so it only executes once, as you've observed. However, I don't recommend executing commands conditionally (cf. https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing#The-problem). If your component is broken in such a way clicks never advance the date picker, the test will never end (e.g. causing CI timeout). If you know the date you're starting at, and the number of clicks it'll take to get to the desired end state, just chuck these inside a for loop to click a fixed number of times before making your assertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example test using the Storybook demo page you mentioned.

It starts with the current month and doesn't have the classes you are using, but you will be able to apply the principle from this working example.

There is an `<iframe>` on the page set up by Storybook, so for this test Cypress needs to go inside that. I used `cypress-iframe` to do so.

```js
import 'cypress-iframe'           

it('moves calendar month back three years', () => {

  cy.visit('https://react-dates.github.io/react-dates/?path=/story/drp-calendar-props--single-month');

  // move inside Storybook iframe
  cy.iframe().within(() => {

    const monthSelector = '[aria-label="Calendar"] [data-visible="true"] strong'
    const backSelector = '[aria-label^="Move backward"]'

    cy.get(monthSelector).should('contain', 'November 2022')

    for (let index = 0; index < 36; index++) {             // want 3 years of clicks

      cy.get(monthSelector).invoke('text')
        .then(previous => {                                
          cy.get(backSelector).click()
          cy.wait(100, {log:false})      
          cy.get(monthSelector).should('not.have.text', previous)                               
        })
    }
    cy.get(monthSelector).should('contain', 'November 2019')
  })
})
```

**Note**

Checking the month text has changed should be enough to wait for each transition, but in practice I found the test to be flaky with that check alone.

Adding a `cy.wait(100)` solved the flakiness. There could be something else to check instead, but without diving in to source code it's difficult to see what it is. The wait is pragmatic in this scenario to get the test working.